# one django project - render different content depending on domain

Tags: python, django, django-sites

I seem to be using django's `site` framework. :) BUT. here what I dont understand:

**How to write dynamic views to check current domain and render proper content to that domain**

what I did is: (I have one single django project with single settings.py)

1. created 2 extra `settings__domainname.py` files with `SITE_ID` set to respective ID of Site object in db
2. in view:

   ```
   if get_current_site(self.request).domain == "domain-usa.com":
     context['allnews'] = News.objects.filter(country='USA')
   elif get_current_site(self.request).domain == "domain-hun.com":
     context['allnews'] = News.objects.filter(country='Hungary')
   ```

I am running the dev server like `./manage.py runserver --settings=myproj.settings_domainname`

But I am hard-coding it anyways, i want my views to check and get content totally dynamically without any hardcoding.

How can I achieve this? I am trying to make the life of my coworkers (who may want create new domain thru admin) and of mine (have to hardcode in views) easy.

any guidance is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - almost the solution:**.

I extended the Site Model like this:

```
class CustomSite(models.Model):
   sites = models.OneToOneField(Site, null=True, related_name='customsite')
   COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
       ('en', 'USA'),
       ('de', 'Germany'),
       ('es', 'Spain'),
       ('ru', 'Russia'),
       ('fr', 'French')
   )
   country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return 'Country of {0}'.format(self.sites.domain)
```

and in view, I can do:

```
country_ofdomain = get_current_site(self.request).customsite.country
news_for_this_country = News.objects.filter(country=country_ofdomain)
```

Does this make sense? Aaand, as usual, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit you `hosts` file (/etc/hosts in unix, mac or C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts at windows)  and add some domains, like this:

```
127.0.0.1    domain-usa.com
127.0.0.1    domain-hun.com
```

after this, run dev server as public (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000)
and go to url http://domain-usa.com:8000/

`get_current_site` look at SITE_ID in your settings, but you need to get `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` variable, and get domain from it.

Comment: thanks, dude. I figured out another weird solution for this. I extended the Site Model and put another field called ``country``. wow it is getting amazing with every step :D